# formulation between number of arcs and number of points on a circle

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometric-integrals

I have n points (equally spaced) on the circumference of a circle, and I want to divide this circle into m arcs. Each arc could hold one to n-(m-1) points. How do I formulate the possibilities of the position of each arc?
ex. Ten points on the circumference of the circle and I want to divide this circle into two arcs, then the search space of the position of each arc is ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To separate $10$ points on a circle into $2$ arcs you choose $2$ of the $10$ circular segments between your points to contain the endpoints of your $2$ arcs. You can do that $\binom{10}{2} = 10 \times 9 /2 = 45$ ways.

Do you see how to generalize?

**Edit** in response to comment.

For $n$ points and $m$ arcs you choose where to place the $m$ division points in
$$
\binom{n}{m} = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{m!}
$$
ways.

Comment: this means for n points and m arcs, n x (n-1)/m

Comment: No. You have to think about what you're counting, not just generalize the formula. See my edit. Look up _binomial coefficients_.

Comment: for a large number of m and n, how could I diminish this search space?

Comment: You can't shrink the search space without more restrictions. That's just how many possibilities there are.

Comment: If I want to set a minimum or maximum limit on the number of points in each segment, how can I do that?

Comment: That would make it much harder to count the number of configurations.There is probably no simple formula. If you want more help you should [edit] the question to include the limits you expect to impose.  It might also help to tell us where the question comes from, about how large the inputs are, and what you want do do with the answer. Then calculate some easy cases by brute force, or write a program. (Since you have accepted my answer, if you want to ask further you should write a new question and link to this one.)

Comment: I want to limit the search space of assigning n jobs to m machines, as I want to calculate the best population size to train GA to solve this problem, which changes according to n and m.

Comment: Last comment in this thread. Your problem is not well formulated mathematics, so not appropriate for this site. You can generate configurations randomly by choosing a first segment for an end point, then choosing the next segment for an endpoint clockwise at a distance between your max and min, and so on. You will often reach an impasse, but then you just start again. This might sample well enough from the search space to help.